Why can we assign an item in a tuple and modify it and that can change the tuple, but same is not possible with list?
I can assign an item(a list inside tuple) in the tuple to a variable and can make changes to that variable and that reflects in the tuple. I could do the same with nested list though if this works only when I assign list inside the list. However that doesn't work with a simple list. How does assigning different value to a variable change the list or tuple? Below is the sample code and output. I am very new to python and coding, so excuse my if I couldn't frame the question, right way.
tuple1 = 1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]
print(tuple1)
x = tuple1[-1]
x[2] = 10
print(tuple1)

Output :
(1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3])
(1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 10])
....................................

list1 = [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]
print(list1)
x = list1[-1]
x[2] = 10
print(list1)

Output:
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 10]]
....................................

list2 = [1, 2, 3]
print(list2)
x = list2[0]
x = 10
print(list2)

Output :
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]

Am learning python and I always thought making changes to a variable wouldn't make difference to anything else.

In your last code fragment x = list2[0] assigns a value to a new variable (x). Think of it as a copy of the value at list2[0]. You then assign 10 to x. x becomes a new instance because int objects are immutable. Therefore, there is no effect on the list from whence it came

Assigning a new value to x does not modify the value that was previously held by x.

Mandatory link to Ned Batchelder

@SIGHUP so basically if I assign a mutable object to variable, making changes in variable  make changes to where it came?

The difference is whether you assign a new value to a variable, or to an index/key/attribute of a mutable object.

@deceze I kind of understood. However I still don't understand,  in first two methods it only assigns index/key/attribute of the object but in 3rd case it assigns new value? Is it something far too complicated for beginner?

You can't make a reference to an int. In other words x is not a reference in your int example. It's just an alias. x does not point back to where it came from, it just IS an int.

The only difference to consider is whether you are assigning to a variable or to an attribute of a variable. Assigning to a variable (x=10) shifts the attention of the variable to somewhere else. Assigning to an attribute (x[2] = 10) doesn't change where the variable references.
